# How can I specify run-time variables in a jar's manifest file?

Tags: java

More specifically, when I run my java program from the command line before I jar it, I do something like this:

```
java -cp  a.jar;b.jar;c.jar;. -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=jssecacerts  Main
```

I can put the jar's into the Manifest file like so:

```
Class-Path: a.jar b.jar c.jar
```

And then create the jar file like this:
    jar -cmf MANIFEST Main.jar Main.class

So that when I run it, I can just write:

```
java -jar Main.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=jssecacerts
```

However, I'd like to simplify my command line even further and specify the -D variable inside the manifest if possible. Based on this reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

It doesn't seem obvious how to do it, so I'm wondering if there's any way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it by setting anything in the manifest, however [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t129370-vm-arguments-in-manifest.html) provides some interesting alternatives that you might consider.

In general, you could put a properties file in your Jar file and access it via the classpath (`Class.getResourceAsStream()`) so that will have close to the same effect and you won't have to change your code when you need to reset properties.

Comment: I used the static class initialization block with System.setProperty().